# DNS - Hosting domain - IP provided by ISP

Tags: dns

First of all, I am really sorry, still new on the use of Ubuntu and server administration. But I am eager to learn!

I purchased an unmanaged VPS server (Ubuntu 12.10) with 2 IP addresses + a domain name.
I would like to setup the DNS for my domain name to be redirected to my website (no mail server etc...).

I am mostly following this tutorial:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Host-Your-Own-Domain-With-Bind9-on-Ubuntu-49585.shtml

and also use these tutorials for help:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236093

and another one... (not enough reputation to post it here :) )

But I have few questions:

1. I don't understand what is the "DNS IP address provided by your ISP".
2. Also, when I edit my domain name (on my host website), I have to set the primary nameserver and the secondary nameserver. I guess it will be like `ns1.my-domain.com` and `ns2.my-domain.com`, but which IP should I give to `ns1` and which to `ns2`?
3. In the tutorials, I never see `ns2`, it's normal because it's not a primary?

Again I am really sorry for my small knowledge.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Best!

Doudou

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to have your domain pointing towards your server.

1. Go to your domain manager or domain acount from where ever you have bought the domain.
2. Edit nameservers for the domain.
3. Put the IP address of your server in place of nameserverone and nameservertwo.
4. In your server you should have LAMP installed or any popular control panel (CPanel or Plesk) there are some opensource and free as well. to have control panel is optional but recommended to make life easier.
5. Than in control panel you can setup new domain acount and dns to as you wish. You can add nameserver entries.(NS)
6. Or you can have webmin installed on your server thats free it can help you manage your server dns, and everything.

Comment: Thanks Yousaf. Unfortunately one of my requirement is to not have any GUI on the server. It's why I was looking to the links provided in my email and was interested by "bind". And just for information, LAMP is well installed and my website well setup. My concern is really only the domain name...

Comment: By using webmin you will have access to bind9. its not GUI its webbased administration panel. you will access webmin like this. http://your-server-ip:port/. Believe me it will make your life easier. you need to have activate several apache modules like user_dir to get everything working. just doing this on shell for beginers can ends up breaking the server

Comment: Ok, you convinced me :) Indeed webmin is much more easy to use. I did your point 1,2,3 and 6. I followed this for setting up my nameservers on webmin: http://dhru.com/knowledgebase/52/How-do-I-setup-nameservers-in-Webmin-or-Virtualmin-.html but I am still confused on why I need 2 IPs, and how to configure CNAME, MX, A etc... And how to specify to ns2 is secondary and follow ns1

Comment: you can use 2 ips but its not obligtory.. 2 ns means 2 different dns servers. if you have one dns server and 2 ip's it realy dont mean much. you can configure both ip's on same server you can go to bind in webmin. create new domain records. and you need to check some tutorial to configure all these things for your domain. Check this tutorial might help you configure bind through webmin
http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/BINDDNSServer